# How to Bind Value of One DropdownList Depending on Other DropDownlist in InfoPath?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010, infopath-forms-services

I have a DropDownList which is populated with One SharePointList in INFOPATH and the value for other textboxes are filled depending on this DropDownList Selected Value using Rules & Action. This works fine.

i have also tried with XML binding it works. But, Now i want to retrieve data using TWO DIFFERENT SHAREPOINT LISTS in DropdownList2 Depending on Value of DropdownList1
(Want to use ClientID as LookUp value)depending on the Selected value of Dropdownlist1 bind corresponding data in DropdownList2.

```
Note: There are two Different Lists(Data Connections)

Eg: ClientList(ClientID,Name,City)
    ClientAddress(ClientID,Address1,Address2)

Depending on `ClientID` from `DropDownList1` the `DropDownList2` or `ListBox` Must contain `Address1` Value from `ClientAddress Sharepoint List` must be filled with Corresponding Address1,Address2.
```

Help Appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to do this in the code behind.

Take the first drop down, find the field it is associated with, right click and create a "Changed" event. Note: Make sure the drop down list control properties has "Always" selected in the Browser Forms tab of the properties (right click on the drop down list to access these properties)

In the code behind event, a Changed event will be created for that field. There you can grab the value of the currently selected item of the first drop down. Depending on that value, you can then modify the contents of the second drop down.

However, if the contents of the second drop down come from an external data source, you will need to grab that data, modify it however you want (depending on the value selected on the first drop down) then programmatically populate the second drop down with that newly modified data.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for Replying @Meyer Denney! I want to do using Rules & Lookup values from these two Lists in InfoPath forms Template and not by using any coding technique!Any Idea?